# Help identifying source of odd requests showing up in server logs

Tags: security

Anyone seen these before? Not sure if this is related to Google Analytics or UserFly running on our site or indicative of automated attacks from user machines.

The requests come from users with all user-agent strings, and from users who make legitimate requests and from trusted users. I've matched the string in a mod_rewrite rule to return "forbidden" but I would like to know where these are coming from. They come in waves, nothing for a week or more, than many many requests in one day.

The requests are for many random pages on the site and then have this odd query string appended, which varies but always looks something like:

```
"GET /&data=%7C%23ujnftubnq%23%3B2392714553497-%23fwfout%23%3B%5C%5E-%23efubjmt%23%3B%5C%5E-%23ujnft%23%3B%5C%5E~ HTTP/1.1"
```

Comment: The IP addresses are coming from what kind of blocks? Home users? Private? Asia/Russia?

Comment: If it were Google or something like that, I doubt they'd be spoofing user-agent strings.

Comment: I haven't seen something quite like that, but that first character of data is "%7C"; that's a pipe "|", and that makes me **very, very suspicious**.

Comment: home, corporate, etc, almost all in US. Mostly from customers of this client and corporate partners of this client (this is a client site). As I said, trusted users' IP's are showing up in the logs with these requests.

Comment: Yes, I totally agree that the pipe character seems suspicious; that's one of the things that made me take this one seriously and try to track it, understand it.

Comment: I don't know that the user-agent strings are spoofed. They might be. But it doesn't completely seem like it, since the same users (IP and User-Agents) also make legitimate server requests durning the same session. Perhaps this is some new pre-fetch user agent?

Answer (score 1):

This is (at this point) somewhat of an educated speculation (er, Scientific Wild @SS Guess), but here goes:

**Something's looking for or targeting PDF's**

Here is the URL Decoded query string from your example above:

```
/&data=|#ujnftubnq#;2392714553497-#fwfout#;\^-#efubjmt#;\^-#ujnft#;\^~
```

Googling around for **"fwfout"**, **"efubjmt"** or **"ujnft"** the only results that came back were PDF's.

It's hard to say if that "something" is malicious or not without knowing more about your environment.  It could be something trying to search within PDF conent on your site.  It could be something trying to find something to exploit, given the recent Acrobat vulnerabilities.

I also agree about pipe suspicion, that character always makes me twitch unless I type it in myself.

Comment: Hm. Could be. If it were legitimate, you might think it would be making such requests for resources which actually existed and were PDF files.

Comment: @Devin: yes, agreed.  Random crap like that showing up in my logs always raises my threat-con level.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of things do you have on your server ?

for #ujnftubnq# #efubjmt# google returned me some chinese things about resource reservation on some routers. No idea if it's relevant or not :> Just a notice.

Comment: It's a US-based client's E-Commerce website.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a bit like it could be a botnet attempting to contact you for command & control, especially with the waves.  Either that or infection attempts from a botnet.  If you know one of the clients well enough, it'd be nice to try to gather more info from one of the sources of the URL.  Packet dumps to see if it's contacting other sites, plus just a check to see what process is doing the contacting.